# Set normal map at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, normals

I have a trouble setting normal map via script in unity. I have a normal map and I want to assign it to a material of the target object.

```
renderer.material = new Material(oldMaterial);    
renderer.material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normalTexture);
```

This line works for assigning the texture. But the target object's normal map is not updated until I open inspector and click material component. I can update albedo texture by using this technique and it works.
Is there a function to force material update its properties ? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add that one:

```
renderer.material.shaderKeywords = new string[1]{"_NORMALMAP"};
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I was thinking that normal map is a default keyword found in every shader. But it turns out we have to add a keyword for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to Unity's Docs, you first need to `EnableKeyword` : `_NORMALMAP`. Then, the normal map you provided can be displayed. For more explanation, you can see the following code or [this website](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTexture.html).

```
//Fetch the Renderer from the GameObject
renderer = GetComponent<Renderer> ();

//Make sure to enable the Keywords
renderer.material.EnableKeyword ("_NORMALMAP");

//Set the Normal map using the Texture
renderer.material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normalTexture);
```